# Extracting corresponding other values in mutate when group_by is applied

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame with **patient data** and measurements of different variables *over time*.

The data frame looks a bit like this but more lab-values variables:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2), 
                 time=c(0,3,7,35,0,7,14,28,42), 
                 labvalue1=c(4.04,NA,2.93,NA,NA,3.78,3.66,NA,2.54),
                 labvalue2=c(NA,63.8,62.8,61.2,78.1,NA,77.6,75.3,NA))

> df2
  id time labvalue1 labvalue2
1  1    0      4.04        NA
2  1    3        NA      63.8
3  1    7      2.93      62.8
4  1   35        NA      61.2
5  2    0        NA      78.1
6  2    7      3.78        NA
7  2   14      3.66      77.6
8  2   28        NA      75.3
9  2   42      2.54        NA
```

I want to calculate for each patient (with unique ID) the decrease or slope *per day* for the first and last measurement. To compare the slopes between patients. Time is in days. So, eventually I want a new variable, e.g. diff_labvalues - for each value, that gives me for labvalue1:

For patient 1: `(2.93-4.04)/ (7-0)`  and for patient 2: `(2.54-3.78)/(42-7)` (for now ignoring the measurements in between, just last-first); etc for labvalue2, and so forth.

So far I have used dplyr, created the *first1* and *last1* functions, because first() and last() did not work with the NA values.
Thereafter, I have grouped_by 'id', used mutate_all (because there are more lab-values in the original df) calculated the difference between the last1() and first1() lab-values for that patient.

But cannot find HOW to extract the values of the corresponding time values (the delta-time value) which I need to calculate the slope of the decline.

Eventually I want something like this (last line):

```
first1 <- function(x) { 
  first(na.omit(x))
}

last1 <- function(x) {
  last(na.omit(x))
} 
df2 = df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate_all(funs(diff=(last1(.)-first1(.)) / #it works until here
  (time[position of last1(.)]-time[position of first1(.)]))) #something like this
```

Not sure if tidyverse even has a solution for this, so any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

We can try

```
df %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   filter(!is.na(labs)) %>% 
   summarise(diff_labs = (last(labs) - first(labs))/(last(time) - first(time)))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#     id   diff_labs
#   <dbl>       <dbl>
#1     1 -0.15857143
#2     2 -0.03542857
```

and

```
> (2.93-4.04)/ (7-0)
#[1] -0.1585714
> (2.54-3.78)/(42-7) 
#[1] -0.03542857
```

---

Or another option is `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[!is.na(labs), .(diff_labs = (labs[.N] - labs[1])/(time[.N] - time[1])) , id]
#   id   diff_labs
#1:  1 -0.15857143
#2:  2 -0.03542857
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, your solution would work if the dataframe had only 1 variable, but I have 49 variables of which I want to compute the slope, so I've tried the following:

`df2 = df%>%
  group_by(subject_id) %>%
  filter_(!is.na(.)) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(diff=(last1(.)-first1(.))/(last1(time)-first1(time))))`

But then it will still take the min() and max() time-values and not the time values corresponding to the value and I will get a different slope. 

I have added an extra variable in the dataframe above, to clarify.